# Change to Persistent Query from deprecated PersistentView

Tags: scala, akka, cqrs, leveldb, akka-persistence

I'm using Akka Persistence, with LevelDB as storage plugin, in an application written in Scala. On the query-side, the current implementation uses `PersistentView`, which polls messages from a `PersistentActor`'s journal by just knowing the identifier of the actor.

Now I've learned that `PersistentView` is deprecated, and one is encouraged to use Persistent Query instead. However, I haven't found any thorough description on how to adapt the code from using `PersistentView` to support the preferred Persistence Query implementation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 2.4.x-to-2.5.x [migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#removal-of-persistentview):

> **Removal of PersistentView**
>
> After being deprecated for a long time, and replaced by [Persistence Query](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence-query.html) `PersistentView` has now been removed.
>
> The corresponding query type is `EventsByPersistenceId`. There are several alternatives for connecting the Source to an actor corresponding to a previous `PersistentView` actor which are documented in [Integration](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html).
>
> The consuming actor may be a plain `Actor` or an `PersistentActor` if it needs to store its own state (e.g. `fromSequenceNr` offset).
>
> Please note that Persistence Query is not experimental/may-change anymore in Akka 2.5.0, so you can safely upgrade to it.